# How can grid frequency dropping lead to grid failure

Tags: frequency, load, power-engineering, power-grid, power-generation

From what I understand, frequency variation indicates generation-load imbalance. In particular, when frequency decreases the load demand is greater than generation.

Wouldn't this just lead to the voltage going lower?
Are there other dangers of grid frequency dropping?

Comment: "frequency variation indicates generation-load imbalance". Sounds logical. Where did you read this? I am interested of the source, so I can have a look and maybe be able to reply to you

Comment: Analogy to this, is the genset - when loaded the RPMs begin to lower, but also the current is increased. Even at full throttle the RPM drops, but it's due to overcurrent that it will trip.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios I did a kind of internship at a grid control center. The engineers told us that frequency of the grid is the indicator used for sensing imbalance. I don't have any literature sources but here is a reddit thread [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/3l1d1r/why_does_the_ac_frequency_drop_in_a_power_grid/)

Comment: there is a GCU that manages the main exciter so any voltage variation is managed via the ME current being adjusted.  Also we are talking about fractions of Hz variation here

Answer (score 4):

Frequency reduction is a *symptom* of the generators being overloaded.

What leads to grid failure is overload of the generators, not frequency reduction *per se*.

However, grid interconnect switches often use the frequency as an indication of how loaded the grid is, and are often set to disconnect when the frequency drops below a certain amount, to protect generators or feedlines upstream of the switch. It's this protective pre-emptive removal of additional power into the grid that causes 'cascading blackouts', which are then attributed in reports to 'the grid frequency dropping'.